# Error message in keycloak log after upgrade

Tags: keycloak

I just upgraded from Keycloak 2.3.0 to Keycloak 3.2.1. I used export and import as described here in the documentation:
https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/documentation/server_admin/topics/export-import.html

Everything seems to work fine from the user point of view, but every time a user visits the keycloak login page, an error is logged in keycloak log:

> ERROR [org.keycloak.keys.FailsafeHmacKeyProvider] (default task-10) No
>   active keys found, using failsafe provider, please login to admin
>   console to add keys. Clustering is not supported.

In 2.3.0 this error was not present. What is causing this error, and how can I resolve this?